# How to open new window in asp.net and disable the old one?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an asp.net web page with a link button on it. When I click the button I need a new web page in a new window to be opened. While the new page is open, the old one should not be active. When I close the new page I need to return a value to the old page. Can you tell me how can I do that?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `Modal popup` for this, basically a popup that will take focus and can't return to the containing page until the user closes the popup. You can pass variables in the usual way.

[Link to modal popup documentation](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_modalpopup.ashx)

Comment: I know about this option but I want to avoid it. So if you any other way it would be great.

Comment: As far as I know you can't open a new browser window and prevent the user from switching back to the previous.